# I want to define f^2 to be 1 but leave f undefined

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbols, protected, user-defined-types

I want, for example, for Mathematica to generate 7 + 5f if I write the expression (2+f) (3+f). I always want f^2 to be computed as 1 (or any other value I assign to it) but for f to be a special undefined symbol. If I define f^2:=1 I get a Tag Power is protected error message.

I am a Mathematica newbie, self taught, so please try to answer this in as elementary fashion as possible.

For the record, I am trying to define Clifford algebra operations in n-dimensional space-time and being able to make an assignment like this would tremendously simplify the task.

Comment: We could use UpSet / TagSet `f /: f^2 = 1` but that won't recognize `f^4 == 1` since 4 ≠ 2...

Comment: Chris' answer is just what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Before I close this thread, let me expand the question slightly to see if there is still such an easy solution. The following works: x = (a + a1 e1 + a2 e2 + a3 e3 + a4 e1 e2 - a5 e1 e3 + a6 e2 e3 + 
    a7 e1 e2 e3);  
y = (b + b1 e1 + b2 e2 + b3 e3 + b4 e1 e2 - b5 e1 e3 + b6 e2 e3 + 
    b7 e1 e2 e3);
ReplaceAll[
 Expand[x y], {Power[e1, 2] -> 1, Power[e2, 2] -> 1, 
  Power[e3, 2] -> 1}]

Comment: If a number n is input, can this easily be extended to handle e1, e2, ..., en?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalized to all symbols *e1,e2,e3,...,en*

```
x = (a + a1 e1 + a2 e2 + a3 e3 + a4 e1 e2 - a5 e1 e3 + a6 e2 e3 + 
a7 e1 e2 e3);
y = (b + b1 e1 + b2 e2 + b3 e3 + b4 e1 e2 - b5 e1 e3 + b6 e2 e3 + 
b7 e1 e2 e3);


 ReplaceAll[
   Expand[x y], 
   Power[e_, 2] /; First[Characters[ToString[e]]] === "e" -> 1
 ]
```

---

This way which I have just learned from @Edmund is more elegant:

```
Expand[(2 + e1)(3 + e2)] /.Power[s_Symbol,2]/; StringStartsQ["e"]@SymbolName[s]->1
```

> ```
> 6 + 3 e1 + 2 e2 + e1 e2
> ```

Comment: Are you recycling answers seconds after you get them on other forums?  Poor form, mate. Poor form. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125089

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Both solutions work perfectly on the more general problem. I really appreciate the help. I could not have done this at my current state of learning Mathematica. I was even able to use your techniques to extend this a little more, which I realized was needed after succeeding at this step. I need to allow that a few of the ei's may have squares equal to -1, the rest being +1. I did this by renaming the chosen few from e1 to f1, e2 to f2, etc. Then I applied 2 rules instead of 1, one for e^2 and also one for f^2. Finally I replaced f'1 with e1, f2 with e2, etc. Thanks again

Comment: Edmund, I was not able to find 125089. I don't possess sufficient Mathematica vocabulary yet to search for the terms "pattern matching". Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @Edmund I was trying to solve the OP's problem but I got stuck and the documentation couldn't help me. I learned something new and helped others simultaneously. Btw I found and posted an answer to my own question before you found a better one. How should I approach a situation like this in future?

Answer (score 1):

```
ReplaceAll[Expand[(2 + f) (3 + f)], Power[f, 2] -> 1]
```

> 7 + 5 f